# Moving items from right to left causes the elements to go to the bottom of the rich:pickList

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Moving items from right to left causes the elements to go to the bottom of the [rich:pickList](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_pickList.html)

Assuming I have 5 elements in my pick list and the left hand side shows up as (1,2,3,4,5) and I move to items from the top to the right side.

The list appears as follows left hand side (3,4,5) and right hand side (1,2).

If I move 2 back to the lef, the list appears as follows

left hand side (3,4,5,2) and right hand side appears as (1)

Is there a way to make the "2" item go back to its original position, so that the list appears as (2,3,4,5) instead?

Answer (score 1):

you can use Sorting option.

1. implicit call: instead of ArrayList() use TreeSet(comparator). 
   client side you just need to reRender on listChanged
2. explicit call: suppose you do not want to use TreeSet as mentioned above.
   then call an a4j action method on listChanged sort  ArrayList

   like  Collections.sort(list, compartor);

Hope this helps.